# Запрос к форме ввода сайта из приложения Android

Tags: android

Уважаемые пользователи, новичок в Android и меня интересует каким образом можно сформировать запрос к форме ввода сайта из приложения Android и получить сведения обратно, гугление не помогло, подскажите куда копать или может ссылкой поделитесь

Answer (score 1):

Будет замечательно если у это сайта есть API для взаимодействия с аутентификацией и тому подобное. Если нет - то пожалуй спасет только WebView, через которое придется стучаться к этой форме

Comment: Спасибо, да у сайта нет api, буду гуглить

Answer (score 0):

Распишите, пожалуйста, более детально вашу задачу. Что конкретно вам надо выполнять на этой форме?
Возможно вам следует создать аналогичную форму на андроиде (контролируя ввод данных, включая валидацию) и в конечном счёте отправлять POST запрос, на тот же URL, что и отправляет форма, при этом брать данные из андроид виджетов.
Если вы новичок, я бы советовал отправлять запрос через DefaultHttpClient.

Пример кода для запроса (подставите свои пост данные)

new Thread(new Runnable() {

```
@Override
public void run() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://1.index.php");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Andrew"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "Hello"));
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String request = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        total.append(line);

    return total.toString();
}
```

}).start();

Comment: На сайте есть поля для ввода фамилии, имени и отчества, мне надо чтобы через приложение в эти поля вставить данные, и чтобы ответ вернулся в приложение, имеются ли сведения по заданным ФИО

Comment: Вы знаете по какому POST-запросу происходит отправка данных и какие имена параметров?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не знаю

Comment: Каким образом можно получить эти сведения?

Comment: Отправьте мне ссылку, я попробую найти решение

Comment: http://mvd.gov.by/ru/main.aspx?guid=15791